# how to preselect a multiple option on php loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress

im trying to print an option tag with multiple options preselected, but i have a problem with the html output because the tag is closing before than i want to:

```
$output.=' <option class="opt" ';
  for($f = 0 ; $f < count($p_cargoInteres) ; $f++){
    if($subcategory->term_id == $p_cargoInteres[$f]){
        $output.= 'selected = "true"';
           }
        $output.= ' value="'. esc_attr( $subcategory->term_id ) .'">'. esc_html( $subcategory->name ) .'</option>';
```

but when im trying to print the option tag close before the **'selected'**
[here is how this looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH9f5.png)

There`s a better way to do this?

i'm receiving the var **$p_cargoInteres** like an Array.

This is an updating form, than the people must refill if is necessary, but i must show the last data into the bd

Comment: Have you tried making the if statement into an else also?  I mean that the very last '$output.=.....' should be the else part of the if.

Comment: You are not opening the option tag inside the loop. add <option> after the for loop.

Comment: @CharlesEF i did it, i tried to do with an 'else', but that duplicates the non selected option (i came from another foreach loop)

Comment: @Mehrwarz i came from another foreach

Answer (score 1):

You have set an option tag outside a for a loop. That will create a one option tag only. It should be inside for loop to create multiple options.

```
if($subcategory->parent == $category->term_id) {
    for($f = 0 ; $f < count($p_cargoInteres) ; $f++){
        $output .= ' <option class="opt" ';
        if($subcategory->term_id == $p_cargoInteres[$f]) {
            $output.= 'selected = "true"';
        }
        $output.= ' value="'. esc_attr( $subcategory->term_id ) .'">'. esc_html( $subcategory->name ) .'</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: i forgot to say that im inside a loop of foreach, im comparing two arrays really...

Comment: Still, you need to put the option inside loop (second for). if you could add the arrays I will write the complete loop.

Comment: @Mehrwarz not really, because that 'for' is just for the comparison , im writing the 'option' tag  from another 'for' just before the first 'if' that i put there

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i dont explain the issue well, but i was comparing 2 arrays

1st array with id's of post (to select)
2nd array with saved id's selected before from the bd.

and i was wanting to re-select the past ids just to show the past preferences of the user.

My mistake was putting the last output, (the close of the tag), inside the for loop.

```
if($subcategory->parent == $category->term_id) {
    $output.=' <option class="opt" ';
    for($f = 0 ; $f < count($p_cargoInteres); $f++) {
        if($subcategory->term_id == $p_cargoInteres[$f]) {
            $output.= 'selected = "true"';
        } else {
            $output.= '';
        }
    } /* THIS IS THE FINISH OF THE FOR */
    $output.= ' value="'. esc_attr( $subcategory->term_id ) .'">'. esc_html( $subcategory->name ) .'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You then need to close the for loop after the if statement before the final $output .= 'value="'

```
if($subcategory->parent == $category->term_id) {
    $output .= '<option class="opt" ';
    for ($f = 0; $f < count($p_cargoInteres); $f++) {
        if($subcategory->term_id == $p_cargoInteres[$f]){
            $output.= 'selected="true" ';
        }
    }
    $output.= 'value="'. esc_attr( $subcategory->term_id ) .'">'. esc_html( $subcategory->name ) .'</option>';
}
```